# keep getting ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED exception when calling OTA_AirBookRQ

Tags: c#, sabre

I used the following code to construct the request:

```
            var dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var tstamp = dt.ToString("s") + "Z";

            var msgHeader = new com.Sabre.WebServiceConsumer.LLS.MessageHeader { ConversationId = convid };

            var from = new com.Sabre.WebServiceConsumer.LLS.From();
            var fromPartyId = new com.Sabre.WebServiceConsumer.LLS.PartyId();
            var fromPartyIdArr = new com.Sabre.WebServiceConsumer.LLS.PartyId[1];
            fromPartyId.Value = "WebServiceClient";
            fromPartyIdArr[0] = fromPartyId;
            from.PartyId = fromPartyIdArr;
            msgHeader.From = from;

            var to = new com.Sabre.WebServiceConsumer.LLS.To();
            var toPartyId = new com.Sabre.WebServiceConsumer.LLS.PartyId();
            var toPartyIdArr = new com.Sabre.WebServiceConsumer.LLS.PartyId[1];
            toPartyId.Value = "https://sws3-crt.cert.sabre.com";
            toPartyIdArr[0] = toPartyId;
            to.PartyId = toPartyIdArr;
            msgHeader.To = to;

            msgHeader.CPAId = ipcc;
            msgHeader.Action = "OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ";
            var service = new com.Sabre.WebServiceConsumer.LLS.Service { Value = "AirAvail" };
            msgHeader.Service = service;

            //Create the request object req and the value for the IPCC in the payload of the request.

            var flightSegments = new List<OTA_AirBookRQFlightSegment>();



            foreach (var flightData in itinerary.FlightsData)
            {

                var currSeg = new OTA_AirBookRQFlightSegment()
                                  {
                                      Status = "QF",
                                      FlightNumber = flightData.FlightNum,
                                      NumberInParty = "1",
                                      ResBookDesigCode = "Y",
                                      OriginLocation =
                                          new OTA_AirBookRQFlightSegmentOriginLocation
                                              {
                                                  LocationCode
                                                      =
                                                      flightData
                                                      .Dep
                                              },
                                      DestinationLocation =
                                          new OTA_AirBookRQFlightSegmentDestinationLocation
                                              {
                                                  LocationCode
                                                      =
                                                      flightData
                                                      .Dest
                                              },
                                      MarketingAirline =
                                          new OTA_AirBookRQFlightSegmentMarketingAirline
                                              {
                                                  Code
                                                      =
                                                      flightData
                                                      .Carrier,
                                                  FlightNumber
                                                      =
                                                      flightData
                                                      .FlightNum
                                              },
                                  };

                if (flightData.DepartureDate != null)
                {
                    currSeg.DepartureDateTime = flightData.DepartureDate.Value.ToString("s");
                }
                if (flightData.ArrivalDate != null)
                {
                    currSeg.ArrivalDateTime = flightData.ArrivalDate.Value.ToString("s");
                }
                flightSegments.Add(currSeg);
            }


            var req = new OTA_AirBookRQ {ReturnHostCommand = true, OriginDestinationInformation = flightSegments.ToArray()};

            var msgData = new com.Sabre.WebServiceConsumer.LLS.MessageData
                              {
                                  MessageId =
                                      "mid:20001209-133003-2333@clientofsabre.com1",
                                  Timestamp = tstamp
                              };
            msgHeader.MessageData = msgData;
            var security = new com.Sabre.WebServiceConsumer.LLS.Security1 { BinarySecurityToken = securitytoken };

            var c = new OTA_AirBookPortTypeClient();
            var resp = c.OTA_AirBookRQ(ref msgHeader, ref security, req);
            if (resp.ApplicationResults.status == com.Sabre.WebServiceConsumer.LLS.CompletionCodes.Complete) return true;
```

I got the following exception:

> ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED
>
> Remote Stack trace: Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:

The Itinerary I’m trying to fake book is round trip with the following
segments: DFW->LAS, Departure: 2016-02-07T00:00:00, Arrival:
2016-02-07T00:00:00, Carrier: NK, FlightNumber: 469  LAS->DFW,
Departure: 2016-02-14T00:00:00, Arrival: 2016-02-14T00:00:00, Carrier:
NK, FlightNumber: 470

So I created OTA_AirBookRQ with 2 OTA_AirBookRQFlightSegment in the
OriginDestinationInformation (one for inbound DFW->LAS and one for the
outbound)

I  even tried playing with the date/time format. For instance give :
2016-02-07T00:00 or : 2016-02-07T instead of 2016-02-07T00:00:00 but
got the same exception every time Also tried using only
DepartureDateTime (without arrival date time) and got the same result.

Comment: Can you try posting the serialized XML that gets sent to Sabre?
That way makes it easier to see what's wrong in the request.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the OTA_AirBookLLSRQ, but sending a different Action
msgHeader.Action = "OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ";

If the rest of the request is correct just change to:
msgHeader.Action = "OTA_AirBookLLSRQ";